# Pick a props from type generically

Tags: typescript

How to make a generic type like this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/ATAuE8AcFNgJWgQwCbQE7ALzAN4CgRDgBLZALmADsBXAWwCN0CirFboKBnUNYygc2YgAvkOBiIMeElRoACmgD2kTgB4FyzgD4swOcQDGAa1UIU6ADR6lKrWLEHFlbsAAeFM7I0rVAclK%20Otj4LCTkwACMYqJAA).

```
type Reader = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

type ReaderProps<Props> = Pick<Reader, Props>

const x: ReaderProps<'id'> = {
  id: 1
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `type ReaderProps<Props extends keyof Reader> = Pick<Reader, Props>` or do you want an implementation to copy only the given properties?

Comment: @Caramiriel yep it's what i want, please answer not in comments so i can accept

Comment: You can pick Maciej's answer. I'm not here for the points. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, one thing is missing:

```
type ReaderProps<Props extends keyof Reader> = Pick<Reader, Props>
```

`Props` needs to extend possible props in `Reader` type, so we should use `keyof`.